# rotate element on scroll within a div container

Tags: javascript, html, function, scroll, wrapper

Ok so here's a challenge: I'm looking to rotate a fixed element when you scroll up and down inside a < div > - and **not** when you scroll on the entire page. So how do i target the scroll within a specific < div> (my div has classname="elementor")?

My code so far looks like this:

HTML

```
/* The image i'm trying to rotate */
<img class="portfolio" id="rotatelogo" src="http://jakobnatorp.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/10/cropped-JAKOB-LERCHE-DAA-NATORP.png"/>

/* And a div container with class="elementor" */
```

CSS

```
.portfolio {
  position: fixed;
  width:150px;
  height:150px;
  margin-top:50px;
  margin-bottom:-300px;
  margin-left:50px;
}  

.elementor {
  width: 100vh;
  height: 100vw;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  transform: rotate(-90deg) translateX(-100vh);
  transform-origin: top left;
  -ms-overflow-style: none;
}
```

JS

```
    var element = document.getElementsByClassName("elementor")[0]
    var elem = document.getElementById("rotatelogo");
element.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
    var value = element.scrollY * 0.25;
    elem.style.transform = `translatex(-50%) translatey(-50%) rotate(${value}deg)`; 
});
```

Edit: I changed the code and it works now. I replaced the "scrollY" with "scrollTop". My new JS looks like this:

```
    var element = document.getElementsByClassName("elementor")[0]
    var elem = document.getElementById("rotatelogo");
element.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
    var value = element.scrollTop * 0.25;
    elem.style.transform = `translatex(-50%) translatey(-50%) rotate(${value}deg)`; 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it right, you could select the element you'r adding an event to.

Something like :

```js
const scrollDiv = document.querySelector(".scrollOnMe");
scrollDiv.addEventListener("wheel", () => {
  console.log("Scrolling !");
})
```

```css
div {
  height: 30px;
}
.scrollOnMe {
  background-color: green;
}
.foo {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="scrollOnMe">Scroll on me !</div>
<div class="foo">Don't :(<div>
```

Comment: Hi Martin, thank you for your response. I already did something like that with my "var element" and it works. I figured that my fault was in the ".scrollY" command - i was supposed to use ".scrollTop" instead.